# MySQL function - strange division results?

Tags: mysql, function, rounding, division

I'm seeing some strange behavior in MySQL related to user-created functions.  I'll simplify this as much as possible.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 / 50

+--------+
| 1/50   |
+--------+
| 0.0200 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far so good. Now I create a function to do this division and call the function:

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> create function myd(var decimal) returns decimal language sql deterministic
    -> begin
    ->     declare res decimal;
    ->     set res = var / 50;
    ->     
    ->     return res;
    -> end
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> select myd(1);
+--------+
| myd(1) |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Very strange.  Ok, let's try a few other values:

```
mysql> select myd(10), myd(20), myd(50), myd(70), myd(100);
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| myd(10) | myd(20) | myd(50) | myd(70) | myd(100) |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|       0 |       0 |       1 |       1 |        2 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did a bit more testing - but it's pretty clear from the results that the result of the function is being rounded to an integer value, despite the function being declared as `returns decimal`.  I tried replacing type `decimal` with `float` but that didn't change a bit.

So why is this rounding occurring and, more importantly, how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify a precision for a decimal it will be `DECIMAL(M,0)` by default which is **zero** digits after the comma.

Example: Define it as

```
decimal(10,3)
```

to have 3 digits after the comma.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: Ah! Ok, let me see :)

Answer (score 1):

Decimal declared without precision means 0 precision.

```
mysql> select CAST(1/50 as Decimal);
+-----------------------+
| CAST(1/50 as Decimal) |
+-----------------------+
|                     0 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CAST(1/50 as Decimal(10,4));
+-----------------------------+
| CAST(1/50 as Decimal(10,4)) |
+-----------------------------+
|                      0.0200 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you change it to float or decimal(10,4) , it will work.

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> create function myd6(var float) returns float language sql deterministic begin declare res float; set res = var / 50; return res; end$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> select myd6(1);
+----------------------+
| myd6(1)              |
+----------------------+
| 0.019999999552965164 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: RE: "if you change to flat it will work" - please read my question completely.  I stated there, "I tried replacing type decimal with float but that didn't change a bit."

Comment: @AleksG , but it does work as shown in the snippet in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

need to specify fraction:

```
mysql> SELECT 1/2 ;
+--------+
| 1/2    |
+--------+
| 0.5000 |
+--------+

mysql> SELECT CAST(1 / 50 AS DECIMAL);
+-------------------------+
| CAST(1 / 50 AS DECIMAL) |
+-------------------------+
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(1 / 50 AS DECIMAL(10,2));
+-------------------------------+
| CAST(1 / 50 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) |
+-------------------------------+
|                          0.02 |
+-------------------------------+
```